# Prevent OptionButton preselection in UserForms

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in a UserForm:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Warning_Box.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    KeepGoing = 0
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    KeepGoing = 1
End Sub
```

The first time this code runs, it works fine as none of the OptionButtons is preselected by the VBA code. The second time however, the previous choice is preselected. This appears to stop the correct setting of the `KeepGoing` value (as an earlier section sets `KeepGoing = 2`).

Basically, how do I make it so no OptionButton is preselected after the first run?

Comment: Is `Warning_Box` the name of your UserForm and you're using `Warning_Box.Hide` to close it? If the answer is yes, you're doing it the wrong way. When you call `Hide` method, it *hides* the UserForm and doesn't *close* it, therefore the UserForm keeps its state/values. Change `Warning_Box.Hide` to `Unload Warning_Box` *or simply `Unload Me` if your button is on the same UserForm*.

Comment: Yes Warning_Box is the name of my UserForm.
Thanks for the advice but unfortunately the same issue is occurring when I use Unload instead.

Comment: In this case, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change

```
Warning_Box.Hide
```

to

```
Unload Me
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have good reasons not to use Unload Me. If so, you can just set values of all option buttons to false somewhere in your code.

```
Warning_Box.OptionButton1.Value = False
```

for every option button. You can also loop trough Warning_Box.Controls and set value to false if it is option button.

```
Dim con As Control

For Each con In ufMain.Controls
    If TypeName(con) = "OptionButton" Then con.Value = False
Next con
```